# How to install tipsy plugin for jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

When I download the latest version of jQuery tipsy plugin (0.1.7) from [jQuery plugins page](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/tipsy), the folder contains many folders in it. Is `jquery.tipsy.js` (under the javascript folder) enough or should I put all of folders into my project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the JavaScript file is not the *only* file needed. You should include all of the files found under the `src` folder.

Include the tipsy plugin after including jQuery with `script` tags in your page, either in the `head` or at the end of the `body` tag. You may want to minify the plugin using any of the many online JavaScript minifier available.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.tipsy.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The plugin also requires a CSS file, which can be included using a `link` element in the `head`:

```
<link href="jquery.tipsy.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

The CSS file expect an image `tipsy.gif` to be in the `../images/` directory. This can be edited to refer to the image in any other directory you want. After all that, you can use the plugin by calling the tipsy function as stated in the documentations:

```
$('#example-1').tipsy();
```

Comment: gif does not appear to be needed.